# E-Mail Marketing "Width"

Tags: email, marketing, bulk-email

I am working on building an email marketing newsletter, is there a good general width that I should stick with?   I have seen 600 as a number but I am unsure what others have encountered. I need this to work in as many clients as possible without the dreaded horizontal scroll bar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

600px is generally the max width accepted by the majority of email clients.

[This article](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails/) touches on the subject - they also mention creating a fluid layout, which is possibly the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Usually speaking, you have only 600×100 pixels or less to convince a user to keep reading your email. So yes, you can take 600 as the width limitation.

There're also many other elements you need to take into consideration when designing an email template, such as images, links, contents, etc., here's an [article](http://www.comm100.com/blog/email-marketing-tutorial/designing-your-email-template-5-keys-to-keep-in-mind.html) that may help.